# Sequence alignment diagram with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a DNA alignment diagram. Here is what I have:

```
\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{255,183,236}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{255,249,158}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (read) [rectangle,draw,fill=color1] {TTTCAGATTT};
  \node (refread) at (1,3) [rectangle,draw,fill=color1] {TTTCAGATTT};
  \node at (refread.west) [rectangle,draw,fill=color2,anchor=east] {ACCAGG};
  \node at (refread.east) [rectangle,draw,fill=color2,anchor=west] {AAA};
  \draw[->]{(read) -- (refread)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

How can I make the thing at the top look like a single sequence with its parts highlighted, i.e. more like

[image]

Comment: Not a direct response, but have you looked at the `texshade` package? It is a special-purpose package for highlighting nucleotide and peptide sequence alignments.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that package and I'll keep it in mind. But in this case, I need a different kind of diagram than that package provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw the boxes at the top without frames first, and then a box around them all:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (read) [rectangle,draw,fill=color1] {TTTCAGATTT};

  \node (refread) at (1,3) [rectangle,fill=color1,inner xsep=0pt,line width=0] {TTTCAGATTT};
  \node (first) at (refread.west) [rectangle,fill=color2,anchor=east,inner xsep=0pt,,line width=0] {\,ACCAGG};
  \node (last) at (refread.east) [rectangle,fill=color2,anchor=west,inner xsep=0pt,line width=0] {AAA\,};
  \draw (first.south west) rectangle (last.north east);

  \draw[->]{(read) -- (refread)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Edit: modified to address the white border issue. Box heights didn't change; that was probably just an artifact created by my pdf viewer (from which I took the screen capture).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this still leaves gaps between the parts, which I'd like to avoid (I tried to show it in my "desired" example). I want it to look as if it were a single `ACCAGGTTTCAGATTTAAA` string typeset by TeX.  Also, the AAA box height is a bit smaller than the rest, so there's a white horizontal gap at the bottom. It becomes more visible if you make the fill color dark.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/DEGG9

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Michael's answer:

the box heights were still uneven; I fixed this with `\vphantom` like this:

```
\node at (refread.east) [...] {\vphantom{ACTG}AAA\,};
```